# XML and binary data

Tags: xml, unicode, base64

Why can’t binary data be represented directly in XML, for example, by representing it as Unicode byte values?

I know that we can use base64 to do this but why not Unicode byte values?

Comment: What if the binary data contains the `0x3C` byte? How would you encode it without breaking the XML file?

Comment: When faced with a "why" question, I'm never sure whether you want an accurate historical statement (at what meeting was the decision made, and were the reasons for the decision minuted?) or just conjecture as to why reasonable technical people might have chosen to do it this way? Most usually, the answer is that no-one proposed it, and it therefore wasn't considered. Presumably the reason no-one proposed it is that no-one anticipated a need for it in the area of application that they were thinking about at the time.

Answer (score 0):

XML is **textual** in nature. The XML spec limits which Unicode codepoints are allowed to be used, and requires certain codepoints to be encoded so as not to break XML syntax.  Binary data tends to use byte values that are restricted. Binary data must be encoded in a text-friendly manner.  Base64 satisfies that requirement.  But it is certainly not the only binary-to-text encoding scheme available.